# Differing Floating Point Calculation Results between x86_64 and ARMv8.2-A

Tags: floating-point, fortran, arm, precision

I have compiled the same Fortran libraries and code in both aarch64 and x86_64. It is a model that runs algorithms across n-dimensional arrays / matrices. The ARM CPU is the Amazon Graviton2. AMD & Intel options in AWS produce identical results when the code is compiled and run for x86_64.

I'm using gcc / g++ / gfortran / mpich with the following flags (all version 8.3.0, from debian buster's main repos)

```
-O2 -ftree-vectorize -funroll-loops -w -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -fconvert=big-endian -frecord-marker=4
```

It all compiles and runs fine, however, i notice in the output of the model, the results differ very slightly. It seems to be a matter of precision or rounding, as ***most*** values are the same between output. However, there are (seemingly) random values throughout the output where it looks like the code compiled for one arch either rounded down or truncated and the other arch rounded up.

The output is stored as NetCDF (using NetCDF-Fortran version 4.5.3) and the md5sum of the files is the same across x86_64 CPUs but differs on aarch64.

Any ideas of why this might be happening? Or any flags I can use during compilation to ensure that I get identical results across architectures?

The values I'm looking at now have a precision of 5 decimal places, i.e 123.12345

Here is a snippet from a `diff` of the output where you can see that ***most*** values are identical but a few seem to have been rounded differently (I've marked the differing values with **):

```
  657c657
  <     18.83633, 18.83212, 18.82778, **18.82337**, 18.81886, 18.81425, 18.80956, 
  ---
  >     18.83633, 18.83212, 18.82778, **18.82336**, 18.81886, 18.81425, 18.80956, 
  1151c1151
  <     17.35448, 17.37331, 17.39206, 17.41071, 17.42931, **17.4478**, 17.46622, 
  ---
  >     17.35448, 17.37331, 17.39206, 17.41071, 17.42931, **17.44779**, 17.46622, 
  1711c1711
  <     19.77562, 19.77532, 19.77493, 19.77445, 19.77386, 19.77319, **19.77241**, 
  ---
  >     19.77562, 19.77532, 19.77493, 19.77445, 19.77386, 19.77319, **19.77242**, 
  2130c2130
  <     20.06532, 20.06839, **20.07135**, 20.07423, 20.07702, 20.0797, 20.0823, 
  ---
  >     20.06532, 20.06839, **20.07136**, 20.07423, 20.07702, 20.0797, 20.0823, 
  2140c2140
  <     20.04788, 20.04424, 20.04047, **20.03661**, 20.03268, 20.02863, 20.02448, 
  ---
  >     20.04788, 20.04424, 20.04047, **20.03662**, 20.03268, 20.02863, 20.02448, 
  2600c2600
  <     11.54104, 11.57732, 11.61352, 11.6497, 11.68579, **11.72186**, 11.75784, 
  ---
  >     11.54104, 11.57732, 11.61352, 11.6497, 11.68579, **11.72185**, 11.75784,
```

Comment: Could you please augment your question with the  Arm CPU - not only the architecture - you are using ?

Comment: "precision of 5 decimal places, i.e 123.12345" with floating point numbers this is better expressed as 8 decimal places of precision.  Even better as 24 bits of binary precision.  About what one would expect with [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: "Any ideas of why this might be happening?" -- Perhaps code is using different precision for intermediate calculations.  I suspect some option can turn that off/on.

Comment: @Frant I updated the question to include that I'm using the Amazon Graviton2

Comment: @Marty: Thanks, I updated your questions accordingly: ARMv6 is an old architecture, for which hardware floating point implementation was optional. This is obviously not the case with the Graviton2.

Comment: @Marty: Floating point is not my area of expertise, and I therefore don't feel like I can provide an answer. I would just say that, even though x86_64 and ARMv8-a are implementing the same standard, floating-point computation results may differ - see [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/IeeeCC754%2B%2B-An-Advanced-Set-of-Tools-to-Check-IEEE-H%C3%BCsken/781db72fd3d9bd9190e44cc1183ffcbee7fa57ae?p2df), or the compilers may behave differently in some architecture-related ways: You may want to double-check if there are any architecture-specific rounding/displaying options.

Comment: I suspect you don't understanding floating-point arithmetic.  Try searching for Goldberg's paper on understanding floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @evets Well I suspect you don't understand the question - I'm not performing the floating-point arithmetic, the CPUs are... and they are doing something differently

Comment: This is the expexted precisiin for float (single precision, 32 bit, 4 bytes). The CPUs are different, the assembly will be as well. The optimizations may be different. What sort of operations in particular are different? What is their source code? How do you compile the code? Which flags?

Comment: Another factor may be if the code is threaded. But whatever, if this is single precision this is exactly what I would expect to see. There must be a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Could you post the compile flags? Probably there lies the answer.. Do you use ffast-math or something?

Comment: Also what FP operations are used? Is it only +, -, *, / and sqrt? If other functions such as sin/cos or else is used, the behavior is no surprise...

Comment: Also be aware that those that are identical probably just differ at other decimal places (which you do not print).

Comment: With reference to the comment *This IEEE754 conformance mode is usually the default setting.* in @AndreasH.'s answer below -  I don't believe this is true for Fortran compilers generally, probably because it imposes a performance penalty on f-p intensive codes.  The default is usually 'use whatever f-p the hardware provides and damn the insignificant digits'. I'd advise checking.

Comment: Marty, I'm well aware the cpu is doing the computation.  It is you that seems to be confused by the nuances of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Marty: This would be interesting to display the binary values in hex, as produced by the hardware, instead of decimal, and perform the comparison again. Not sure how easy this is in Fortran versus in C though.

Comment: @Frant would the purpose of this be to just confirm that IO routines are not at play? If so, I've already confirmed that the binary output is not identical between arch's. It is stored in NetCDF format and the md5sum of the files prove there are differences in the ouput (this clue is why i began to investigate)

Comment: @Marty:Yes, this would have been the purpose. You may want to augment your question with the  NetCDF-related information you provided in your comment, since it is of high importance IMHO.

Comment: @Frant you are right, I updated the question to include that NetCDF-Fortran version 4.5.3 is being used to write output to disk

Comment: @AndreasH. I have updated the question to include the compiler flags - although, now I'm realizing that the flags may be different for the underlying NetCDF-Fortran library

Comment: @Marty Thanky. O2 does not seem to imply -ffast-math so it seems you are good here. Regarding the NetCDF library - it should not do any calculation it is just for I/O right? Do I would not be of concern here

Comment: @Marty Could you try Rob's suggestion? i.e. set -ffp-contract=off. (default is "fast") This will disable use of the FMA instruction for multiply and accumulate code sequences, which may be done on ARM but not on x86_64 or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

If the code only uses basic arithmetic operations such as +, -, *, / and sqrt *and* the compiler is in IEEE754 conformance mode, the output should be bit-identical regardless of the CPU used.
This IEEE754 conformance mode is usually the default setting.

Otherwise the issue is probably caused by a compiler or CPU bug.

Options such as `-ffast-math` put the compiler in non-IEEE 754 conformance mode.
It uses then mathematical equivalence rules to optimize the code, which are not necessarily numerically equivalent (e.g., `((a*a)*a)*a -> (a*a)*(a*a)` and such).
If this is the case and the ARM code is optimized differently by the compiler than the x86_64 this may be an explanation.

Also if the code uses functions such as `sin`, `cos`, `exp` `atan2` and such, the output will only be bit-identical if the exact same run-time library is used. This is because these functions are not correctly rounded and results typically have a tiny error (which may amplify in the calculation and show up in the way you observe it).
It also might be the case that for x86_64 special CPU instructions for these functions are used and for ARM a software implementation or vice versa. Note that even if these functions are implemented on the CPU/FPU they are also not correctly rounded and very likely different algorithms are used.

TL/DR: check the compiler flags for `-ffast-math` or try adding `-fno-fast-math` at the end of the options.

EDIT: As @Rob mentioned in the comment another flag that could be added `-ffp-contract=off`. In gcc it is by default 'fast' (independent on `-ffast-math`) which may generate the FMA instruction even when not explicitly requested. This also breaks 754 conformance.

Comment: You forgot that the OP is outputting the data, so there are the IO routines to convert binary to decimal.  IEEE-754 discusses conversion, but it is unclear whether OP has a strictly conforming IEEE-754 IO library.

Comment: Also if the code is threaded or multiprocess something like a reduction can cause this

Comment: Some recent work on a project I work on required when porting the code to arm, showed we needed to set -ffp-contract=off to get better agreement between x86 and arm.

Comment: @evets the diff output was just to demonstrate that there is a rounding difference between arch's, I updated the question to include that the NetCDF binary output itself is indeed different

Comment: @Rob that did seem promising, unfortunately it seems that the gfortran compiler does not have this flag

Comment: Your suggestions of looking for -ffast-math was also promising, but again, it seems that these flags only apply to gcc and not to gfortran

Comment: gfortran understands -ffast-math.  gfortran can use any option that gcc supports with a few exceptions (e.g., those marked as C/C++ only or Ada only).

Comment: @Rob Did you find that you had to use -ffp-contract=off when compiling on both x86 and arm? or did you just use that flag within one architecture? Also, did you notice any performance decrease from doing this?

Comment: We only use it on arm. We didn't bother checking performance as we cared more for getting the same results than speed.